# rails link to nested route not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, rails-routing, nested-resources, nested-routes

I have the following in routes:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :schedules
end
```

I am trying to go to the show schedule page.  Rake routes lists this:

```
project_schedule GET  /projects/:project_id/schedules/:id(.:format)  schedules#show
```

I have the following link on another page to the schedules#show page:

```
<%= link_to 'Show Schedule', project_schedule_path(project.id, schedule.id) %>
```

The page returns the following error:

```
Couldn't find Schedule with id=26
```

Here are the params:

```
{"project_id"=>"26",
 "id"=>"48"}
```

I know a schedule exists with these id's because i can find it in the console:

```
<Schedule id: 48, project_id: 26, created_at: "2013-11-25 19:08:00", updated_at: "2013-11-25 19:08:00">
```

Why isn't the link working?  Thanks.

Comment: The error states that it cannot find Schedule with `id` 26. You are showing the Schedule instance with `id` 48.

Comment: Your shedule id is 48. But you try to find a schedule with id = 26. You are confusing schedule and project id's somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, the link is working, but for some reason now the controller isn't.  I have this is my controller:  @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:project_id], params[:schedule_id]) but it is giving the same error as above.  any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you're trying to find the schedule using the project's id.

I'd do this in your controller:

```
# find the parent model first 
@project = Project.find params[:project_id]

# now get its associated schedule:
@schedule = @project.schedules.find params[:id]
```

You also might have the ids backwards in your link_to helper. You can try using the shortcut:

```
link_to 'Schedule', [project, schedule]
```

That gets converted to the project_schedule_path

Comment: Thanks, the link is working, but for some reason now the show action in the controller isn't. I have this is my controller: @schedule = Schedule.find(params[:project_id], params[:schedule_id]) but it is giving the same error as above. any ideas?

Comment: That is an incorrect way to find the Schedule. You're passing the project_id in to find a schedule and its complaining that it can't find a schedule with that id (the project's id). Try using the code I provided.

Comment: Thats strange, with your code it says: 'undefined method `find' for #<Schedule:0x007f8127d61af0>'

Comment: Which line is throwing that error? It seems like you typed something wrong. Did you copy/paste that code?

Comment: Got it figured out.  Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
  <%= link_to 'Show Schedule', project_schedule_path(schedule.id, project.id) %>
```

Comment: Thanks, tried that, but that takes me to the wrong project.  The project id is 48 and the schedule is is 26, but as you can see in the console, that's not the right project.